# Renaming files with special characters

Tags: command-line

I have a file named "channel\ (3).backup" which I need renamed "channel.backup"

Ive tried several things, but have had no joy.

Any help?

Comment: Try with `mv -i channel*3*.backup channel.backup`; It is a good rule to use `mv -i` in order to avoid overwriting a file by mistake. The wildcards (asterisks) should take care of the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using a wildcard may sometimes help to overcome strange characters that crept in a file name:

```
mv "channel? (3).backup" channel.backup
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy:

```
mv channel\ \(3\).backup   channel.backup
```

or in case the `\` is really in the name and it is not escaped space:

```
mv channel\\\ \(3\).backup channel.backup
```

You must escape all special characters in the file name. They are three or four in your example:

- space   --> `\`
- `(` --> `\(`
- `)` --> `\)`
- `\` --> `\\`

Escaping of the `\` must be done by another `\`, i.e. `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

After `mv channel` hit TAB and it will autocomplete the remainder and will include the escape characters. If there are more files starting with those characters keep hitting tab until the one you want is there and then add the `channel.backup` part.